# How to find the missing edge case in my code

Tags: java, regex, mapreduce, pattern-matching

I am processing tweets using a map reduce job. One of the things I want to do is censor the abusing words. When I test My code locally it works as desired. But when I run it on the whole data set for some text it censors the abusing words but misses some. Now as the data is 1TB in size total(800 files) I am not able to find that particular tweet data in the raw form(JSON) so that I can test it locally to find the problem. However I have the tweet text(not the whole json) which got uncensored from my map reduce program. To test I tried to put that text in the tweet text field of some other tweet json and the program correctly censored the abusing word. Can you guys suggest any strategy by which I can find the bug. Or if you find a bug in my code just by looking at it that would be great
Function which loops through all the words of tweet (tweet split by non alphanumeric character)

public static String censorText(String text, String textWords[], Set banned) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(text);

```
    textWords = getTextArray(text);

    for (int i = 0; i < textWords.length; i++) {

        if (banned.contains(textWords[i].toLowerCase())) {

            String cleanedWord = cencor(textWords[i]);
            // compile a pattern with banned word
            List<Integer> indexList = getIndexes(builder, textWords[i]);
            replaceWithCleanWord(builder, indexList, cleanedWord);
        }
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
//function to find the position of abuse word in the tweet text so     that //can be replaced by censored word
private static List<Integer> getIndexes(StringBuilder builder, String string) {

    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String word = "(" + string.charAt(0) + ")" + string.substring(1);
    System.out.println("word to match" +word);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|[^a-zA-Z\\d])" + word + "(?=$|[^a-zA-Z\\d])");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(builder.toString());
    while (m.find()) {
        indexes.add(m.start());
    }
    return indexes;
}
```

Sample text I want to censor:
    "text":"Gracias a todos los seguidores de cuantoporno y http://t.co/, #sex #sexo #porn #porno #pussy #xxx;"
only if the word is surrounded by special characters or space then censor it
    "text":"Gracias a todos los seguidores de cuantoporno y http://t.co/ , #s*x #sexo #porn #porno #p***y #xxx;"

The first text is the output of my map reduce but expected output is second text. When I input the same text on my local machine for the same java file I get the expected result. What could be the problem?

Comment: To make it better readable you could replace [^a-zA-Z\\d] by \W (no alphanumerics), right? Why is the first character in parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

You do not use any regex feature other than lookahed/lookbehind. Lookahead and lookbehind are not optimized in Java regexp search. You could as well search for the string and then verify if the character before/behind is ok.

This would save a lot of performance:

- compilation of regular expressions is expensive (compared to string search compilation)
- search with regular expressions is even more expensive (compared to string search)

So if you want to solve the problem: Use a **string search algorithm** (as boyer-moore-horspool).

And it gets even more efficient if you use a **multistring search algorithm**, like set-horspool or wu-manber. Such an algorithm will deliver all indexes of all words with a performance of nearly O(n) (n is the length of the text).